# Angular file includes and separation - Best practice

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have 3 different links on my homepage. I am trying to have each link go to a page that looks something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/common/temlate1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-include="'/assets/common/template1.html'" ng-controller="ControlsCtrl"></div>
<script src="/assets/common/template1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

I need each link on homepage to have different css, html and js files associated with it. For example:

If I click link 1: the file will look like the one above. If I click link 2, the file will look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/common/temlate2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-include="'/assets/common/template2.html'" ng-controller="ControlsCtrl"></div>
<script src="/assets/common/template2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

And the third link will have the files:
template3.css
template3.html
template3.js

What is the best way to accomplish what I want. I do NOT want to include all css and js files together. What I mean is I do not want to have this at the bottom of my file: The same is true for the css files.

```
<script src="/assets/common/template1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/common/template2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/common/template3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am only showing you a small portion of the website so that this question is easy to understand. I have a lot of other links in the head section and a lot of js links above the body tag. All of these are common to all 3 templates. Therefore, I would like to use the same file and just replace the 3 areas mentioned above.

How do I accomplish this? I am hoping for a solution in angular. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to define different modules within AngularJS to accomplish this. They can each have their own template.

So in short:

```
angular.module('page1');
angular.module('page2');
angular.module('page3');
```

They can all have their own templates, respectively page1.html, page2.html, and so on ...

This looks like a good explanation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module